# checking number with regex if it is match or not

Tags: java, android, regex, xml

**EditText view**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputField"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/input_placeholder"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

**class for hold number**

```
package com.example.kassammustapha.samplecode;
public class regexHolder{

 String patten_one()
{

    return "[2550]{1}[7]{1}[1]{1}[2-9]{1}\\d{6}";
}}
```

**mainActivity**
the problem is when user enter the number from editText from the view, i receive the number and convert it into string then i test with regular expression but it won't work i dont what is the problems.

```
regexHolder operatorPatterns = new regexHolder();

    final Pattern tigoOne = Pattern.compile(operatorPatterns.patten_one());


    Button mBtn =findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);


    mBtn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                EditText texEdit = findViewById(R.id.inputField);
                TextView viewText = findViewById(R.id.operatorDisplay);

                String content = texEdit.getText().toString();

                Matcher tigoMatcher = tigoOne.matcher(content);

                public void onClick(View view)
                {

                    if (tigoMatcher.matches())
                    {
                        String message = "valid";
                        viewText.setText(message);

                    }else{
                        String message = "not valid";
                        viewText.setText(message);
                    }
                }
            }

    );
```

Comment: Re: "but it won't work", well, what's it do exactly?

Comment: What is your regex supposed to do? `[2550]` looks weird.

Comment: @I'L'I when am trying to test if it matches or not, see on the `if section` but it will provide invalid number while the entered number is valid

Comment: @Sweeper `[2550]` this regex it used to check the 225 or 0 which is started on number

Comment: You don't need those `{1}`s because they are useless. And regex for "225 or 0" is `(225|0)`. not `[2550]`.

Comment: We’d love to help. Therefore please explain precisely first what your regular expression is supposed to match and next how observed behaviour differs (this is always a good idea when asking about code that doesn’t work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix your regex. From your attempted regex and your comments, I am guessing that you want this:

```
(?:255|0)71[2-9]\\d{6}
```

Start with either 255 or 0, followed by 71, followed by a digit that is in the range 2-9, followed by 6 other digits.

Secondly, fix your on click listener.

These two lines:

```
String content = texEdit.getText().toString();

Matcher tigoMatcher = tigoOne.matcher(content);
```

Will be run the instant you create the listener, at which point the text edit is empty. You need to move these lines to the `onClick` method:

```
new View.OnClickListener()
{
    EditText texEdit = findViewById(R.id.inputField);
    TextView viewText = findViewById(R.id.operatorDisplay);

    public void onClick(View view)
    {

        String content = texEdit.getText().toString();

        Matcher tigoMatcher = tigoOne.matcher(content);

        if (tigoMatcher.matches())
        {
            String message = "valid";
            viewText.setText(message);

        }else{
            String message = "not valid";
            viewText.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I don't get cast idea and what does mean, please help

Comment: thanks right now it works but I don't get the cast idea and what is mean, please explain

Comment: @Kassambinary If it works then ignore my comment about casting. I haven't done Android in a while. I thought you need to do `EditText texEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputField);`, but you are using the generic `findViewById` in Android O, so you don't need to cast.